# Serial Output to Arduino LED Display

Tags: arduino, led

I recently completed this project with my Arduino (a fairly new hobby for me):

http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-24X6-LED-matrix/?ALLSTEPS

I can change the code to make whatever messages I want scroll accross the matrix but I thought it might be cool to have live information, like stock quotes, scroll accross.  I think I could figure out how to do that except I would like to use it at work where there are lots of firewalls in place and I doubt Arduino software is on the approved list of programs.  Is it possible to send messages to the Arduino through a USB without installing any drivers?

Answer (score 0):

No it is impossible because data in Arduino is sent via serial command, the USB is only for convenience, but arduino work with FTD driver that emulate a serial connection. You should choose another type of connection bluetooth or wifi.
Hope this help you.

Comment: Would it be possible to program an ATtiny to do this?  That would have the added benefit of freeing up my arduino for other projects.

Comment: Hello, well without installing any drivers you have 2 options, with a bluetooth shield, or you can get an Arduino Yun, on which you can make an open network access point, with a mini server, service, where you can submit your strings to be updated with Yun also have much more memory available, and to write messages do you need a lot;) 
nice project!

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that.  Like I said, I am still kind of new to this.